# NSTableViewDelegate SelectionDidChange and getting notified when clicked again

Tags: cocoa

I'm using the SelectionDidChange form NSTableViewDelegate to alter some data based on the selection and then have the NSTableView reload it again (which will alter the cell's custom control state).
This works great, but I cannot get any notification when clicking a row that is already selected. 
I would need something like a "SelectionDidNotChange".

Anyone?

Comment: Just figured out that I can use the NSTableView action to get notified for mouse click and get the selected row.

Comment: SelectionDidChange will called whenever you row selection willchange  Try this-   - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex